# Naming the iOS Application with ++ Characters

Tags: ios

I have build an application which is called "MyStuff++". The "++" is part of the name. I can easily run the application on my device and the simulator but when I try to upload the application to the app store it complains about the EXECUTABLE_NAME which is set to "MyStuff++". What can I do to solve this issue?

Here is the actual error:

[image]

Comment: Don't put ++ in the bundle name.

Comment: Should it be possible to set in under "Bundle display name" on the .plist file ?

Comment: @Almo But thats the name of the app which should come under the app icon.

Comment: It's the executable name that's causing the issue.  That is fixed in the build settings.

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo Thanks! I believe you are correct. It is the bundle display name that I need to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the *Product Name* (the name given to the executable file) that needs changing to remove the `++`.

This is found under *Target* > *Build Settings* > *Product Name*.

Comment: True! But then I do want the icon to say ++ so I added the bundle display name which works great!